# How to find closest time?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, join, group-by

- Table `A` has fields `RefuelId` and `RefuelTime`. Records the time I refuel my car.
- Table `B` has fields `Price` and `UpdateTime`. Records the price and the time when the gasoline price is updated.
- Result wanted: `A.RefuelId`, `A.RefuelTime`, `B.Price`, `B.UpdateTime`.

`B.Update` is the closet time before `RefuelTime`. Have tried `left join`, but there is no common field between Table `A` and `B`. Return Cartesian product.

Table `A`, `RefuelRecord`:

| RefuelId | RefuelTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 12:15:00 |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 12:15:00 |
| 3 | 2022-04-01 12:15:00 |

Table `B`, `GasUpdateRecord` :

| UpdateTime, | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-20 0:00:00 | 9.0 |
| 2022-02-20 0:00:00 | 8.1 |
| 2022-03-20 0:00:00 | 7.2 |

Result table:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 12:15:00 | 2022-01-20 0:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 12:15:00 | 2022-02-20 0:00:00 |
| 3 | 2022-04-01 12:15:00 | 2022-03-20 0:00:00 |

SQL:

```
Create table RefuelRecord (RefuelId int, RefuelTime datetime);
INSERT INTO RefuelRecord VALUES(1, '2022-02-01 12:15:00');
INSERT INTO RefuelRecord VALUES(2, '2022-03-01 12:15:00');
INSERT INTO RefuelRecord VALUES(3, '2022-04-01 12:15:00');

Create table PriceUpdateRecord (UpdateTime datetime, Price double);
INSERT INTO PriceUpdateRecord VALUES('2022-01-20 12:15:00', 9.0);
INSERT INTO PriceUpdateRecord VALUES('2022-02-20 12:15:00', 8.0);
INSERT INTO PriceUpdateRecord VALUES('2022-03-20 12:15:00', 7.0);
```

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_. (Not records or fields.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `LEFT` join of `RefuelRecord` to `PriceUpdateRecord` on the condition that `UpdateTime` should be less than `RefuelTime`.
Then use aggregation and [SQLite's feature of bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query) to get for each `RefuelId` the row from `PriceUpdateRecord` with the max `UpdateTime`:

```
SELECT r.RefuelId, 
       r.RefuelTime,
       MAX(p.UpdateTime) UpdateTime,
       p.Price
FROM RefuelRecord r LEFT JOIN PriceUpdateRecord p
ON p.UpdateTime < r.RefuelTime
GROUP BY RefuelId;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wPeKacGvvErXJzAcVobxvv/0).